# Optimizer not using Index

Tags: oracle11g, database-performance

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    LTLT.LTLT_PFX, LTLT.ACAC_ACC_NO, LTLT.LTLT_DESC, LTLT.LTLT_CAT, LTLT.LTLT_LEVEL,
    LTLT.LTLT_PERIOD_IND, LTLT.LTLT_RULE, LTLT.LTLT_IX_IND, LTLT.LTLT_IX_TYPE, LTLT.EXCD_ID,
    LTLT.LTLT_AMT1, LTLT.LTLT_AMT2, LTLT.LTLT_OPTS, LTLT.LTLT_SAL_IND, LTLT.LTLT_DAYS, LTLT.WMDS_SEQ_NO,
    LTLT.LTLT_LOCK_TOKEN, LTLT.ATXR_SOURCE_ID, LTLT.SYS_LAST_UPD_DTM, LTLT.SYS_USUS_ID, LTLT.SYS_DBUSER_ID,
    LTLT.LTLT_EXCL_DED_IND_NVL
FROM AGP.TABLE_1 DISB_CLM
INNER JOIN TABLE_2 CLCL ON DISB_CLM.CLCL_ID = CLCL.CLCL_ID
INNER JOIN TABLE_3 PDVC ON PDVC.PDPD_ID = CLCL.PDPD_ID
INNER JOIN TABLE_4 LTLT ON LTLT.LTLT_PFX = PDVC.LTLT_PFX
```

Issue: Optimizer not using index despite a composite index on TABLE_3 and TABLE_4.

Description:

TABLE_4 has the following unique index created:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX DB.CMCX_LTLT_PRIMARY ON DB.TABLE_4 
(LTLT_PFX, ACAC_ACC_NO)
```

TABLE_3 has the following unique index created:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX DB.CMCX_PDVC_PRIMARY ON DB.TABLE_3 
(PDPD_ID, PDVC_TIER, PDVC_TYPE, PDVC_EFF_DT, PDVC_SEQ_NO)
```

[image]

The optimizer uses full table scans for the two tables even though indexes exist for both the tables. The indexes are multi-column indexes but the order of columns
is in accordance with the SQL Server docs and the optimizer should use the index. The query currently takes 40-50 mins to run.

NB: The database DB is owned by a different team, who would not be taking any requests for altering the indexes. The only option is to tweak the query or use explicit hints to use the index.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @James Z

Answer (score 1):

The optimizer is something like an *artificial intelligence*. It makes decisions based on information it has. If those information are accurate, up-to-date, then decision is more likely to be *good*.

Therefore: did you collect statistics, and do you do that regularly? (If you're used to another term (from previous Oracle database versions), the question would be "did you analyze the index?").

If statistics are OK, and if optimizer uses full table scan nonetheles, note that full table scan isn't *evil*. There are situations where it produces a better result than the one *with* index. If you want to make it use it, then apply an appropriate hint. It is usually said that - if you don't know what you are doing, don't use hints as you might make things worse.

Because, performance tuning isn't a simple task - there are books written about it. If it was that easy, everyone would do it efficiently. Sadly, truth is just the opposite. If you want, have a look at Performance tuning sticky topic on OraFAQ Forum, here: http://www.orafaq.com/forum/t/84315/. People have collected some *hints* for us (humans) to make that task somewhat simpler.